# What is a good (strict) upperbound for the probability for having at least $c*N$ (where $c \leq 1$) successes in $N$ trials?

Tags: probability

I have $N$ trials, where I succeed each trial with probability $p$.  If we ask for the probability of having at least $q$ successes, using the binomial distribution we can write this as the sum:

$P[\geq q$ successes$]=\sum^{N}_{i=q}$${N} \choose {i}$$p^i*(1-p)^{N-i} = $${N} \choose {q}$ $[(1-p)^{N-q} p^q]$ $[$$_2F_1(1,q-N,1+q,\frac{p}{p-1})]$ (where $_2F_1$ is the hypergeometric function)

Which is a bit unpleasant looking.  Now imagine that I set $q = Floor[cN]$ (or $q = Ceiling[cN]$ if that makes any difference), where $c \leq 1$ is a constant.

What is a good, simple, and strict upperbound for $P[\geq q$ successes$]$?  Should I be concerned about the normal approximation to the binomial distribution with small values of $N$?

Notice: I made a typo earlier when calculating an exact value for $P[\geq q$ successes$]$.  The new result should be correct, but hardly seems to simplify things.

When, if ever, is it fair to say that the probability decreases at least exponentially with fixed $p$ and increasing $N$?

Comment: Using the Markov inequality you get
$$
  \Bbb P\left[\sum_{i=1}^N X_i \geq cN\right]\leq \frac{1}{(cN)^m}\Bbb E\left[\sum_{i=1}^N X_i\right]^m
$$
which for the case $m = 1$ doesn't give you anything interesting, but for $N = 2$ you get $\leq \frac{q}{c^2N}$. These bounds are clearly not tight, though I don't know what you meant by `strict bounds`.

Comment: @Ilya Thanks, your comment is very helpful.  By "strict bounds" I mean that the upperbound should never underapproximate the probability for $N > 0$.  Is there a more appropriate way to specify this?

Comment: No, I think this is the best way to say this. I understand your point: often you're provided only asymptotic bounds that are not necessarily strict. The bounds above are strict, but are not tight - namely the only overapproximate the right-hand side, but it doesn't mean e.g. that they converge to the actual value.

Comment: In which regime? Asymptotically when $N\to\infty$ or for a fixed $N$? For $c\lt p$ or $c\gt p$?

Comment: @Did For $N\to\infty$ and for arbitrary $c$ (but if forced to specify something, I'll set $c>p$).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The regime $c\gt p$ fixed, $N\to\infty$, is called a *large deviations event* since, if each random variable $X_N$ is binomial $(N,p)$, $P[X_N\geqslant cN]\to0$. The general idea in this situation is that
$$
P[X_N\geqslant cN]\leqslant\mathrm e^{-N\cdot I(c)},\qquad P[X_N\geqslant cN]=\mathrm e^{-N\cdot I(c)+o(N)},
$$
for some $I(c)$ which is obtained by optimizing the exponential inequality bounding $P[X_N\geqslant cN]$. More concretely, note that for every $t\gt0$,
$$
P[X_N\geqslant cN]\leqslant\mathrm e^{-tcN}E[\mathrm e^{tX_N}]=\mathrm e^{-tcN}(1-p+p\mathrm e^t)^N.
$$
Thus, 
$$
I(c)=\max\{I(t,c)\,;\,t\geqslant0\},\qquad I(t,c)=tc-\log(1-p+p\mathrm e^t).
$$
Note that the condition $c\gt p$ ensures that the derivative of $I(\cdot,c)$ at $0$ is positive, thus $I(c)\gt0$ (of course, one can also get an explicit formula for $I(c)$ and check this on the formula).